# Responsive within a certain range

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

```
<div className="px-14 md:px-48 p-8 md:pt-12">
            <ul className="w-full">
              <li className="grid grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-4 border-2 rounded-2xl border-[#002D74] h-[98px] md:h-[156px] px-6 md:px-8">  
                <div className="col-span-3 flex items-center">
                  <img
                    className="md:h-24 md:w-24 h-14 w-14 pl-1"
                    src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/bDCkDV64ZPT38q44KBEWgicFt2gDHdYPgCHbA3knlieeYpNqbliEqBI90Wr6Tu8YOw"
                  />

  --> this line   <div className="pl-4 md:pl-14 md:text-3xl text-sm min-[750px]:max-[1177px]:font-bold  pt-1 md:pt-3"> 
                    <span id="wallet-name">Paypal wallet</span>
                    <span id="wallet-number" className="block pt-2 md:pt-4">
                      **** *** 352
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-1 flex items-center justify-end">
                  <RiDeleteBin5Fill
                    size="32"
                    color="#BE2C2C"
                  ></RiDeleteBin5Fill>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
 </div>
```

I want to font bold when resize the screen between 750px and 1177px so I did like above. But it didn't work.
Why?

Comment: Please replace with this:
<div className="pl-4 md:pl-14 md:text-3xl text-sm pt-1 md:pt-3 font-normal md:font-bold min-w-[750px] max-w-[1177px]">

Comment: I just font-bold in the range 750-1170px. Outside of that range, the word is normal. The default font is normal so I can not set the font normal

Comment: Ya, absolutely right. Is the solution worked?

Comment: No it didn't work, thank you for your help